# Understanding the use of "de" before "autre"

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs, de

I am aware of "autre" sometimes being a pronoun, typically in conjunction with an article or *de*:

---

un autre - d'autres, l'autre - les autres.

---

But my problem lies in the use of the preposition *de* before what I persieve to be the adjective:

---

n'avoir **d'autre** moyen que

---

(The noun can be replaced by whichever you whish; I have seen "choix" or "solution" used in its place.") I understand why the expression "Avoir d'autres chats à fouetter" has "d'autres": *Chats* is plural, and any adjective preceding it will thus take *de* instead of *des*.

---

But in my example, the noun is singular ... This instance of *de* is the first one that I have found profoundly befuddling.

---

Related question: Would a "positive" construction be *"avoir d'une autre solution"*, *"avoir une autre solution"*, *"avoir d'autre solution"*, or *"avoir autre solution"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mix between:

- de : pluriel indéfini.    de belles fleurs
- (pas) de: singulier négatif.   pas de solution
- (pas) de *comparatif* *substantif* que : comparaison négative.   de plus belle maison que, de pire idée que ..., d'autre idée que ...

négatif:

- ne pas avoir d'autre moyen que +   (singulier)
- de plus grande maison que +  (singulier)

positif:

- avoir un autre moyen que (singulier)
- avoir d'autres moyens que (pluriel)
- avoir une plus grande maison que (singulier)
- avoir de plus belles fleurs que (pluriel)

exemples:

- avoir d'une autre solution : incorrect
- avoir une autre solution : correct
- avoir d'autre solution : incorrect
- avoir autre solution : incorrect